# Would a person telling me what he did understand "You did what?" as a request to repeat what he did?

Tags: sentence-usage

In Italian, if somebody told me what they did, and I would say *Hai fatto cosa?* (*You did what?*), it would be probably understood as I am asking to repeat what they did.

How would *You did what?* be understood, in English?

Comment: "What (exactly) you understood?" would be better in my opinion. "You did what?" sounds aggressive and he/she would think that made something bad that have nothing to do with the previous conversation.

Comment: _What exactly did you understand?_ is probably a question the other person should ask me. I cannot ask that if I am listening the other person.

Comment: **[A]** _I went out with your sister._ **[B]** _What exactly did you understand?_

Comment: *You did what?* is fine. (Or, *I'm sorry—you did what?* if you want to address possible issues around politeness. Although tone of voice should be fine for that.) As would be *Could you repeat that (please)?* But asking *What did you understand?* is extremely strange.

Comment: 9 times out of 10, *You did **what**?* would have heavy stress on the highlighted final word. And it wouldn't be so much a request to repeat / clarify what you did - it would be an exclamation / rhetorical question from someone who heard what you said, but was expressing surprise / disappointment / admiration / etc.

Comment: @FumbleFingers What would the sentence mean, if the last word is not stressed?

Comment: Well, it *could* be a genuine enquiry, as in *I'm not sure you helped us very much when we organised the village fete last week. I spent all afternoon running a lucky dip tombola, but you did what?* But in your context of *I just heard you say you did something, but I didn't catch the last word, so **can you repeat it**?* most people would probably say *What did you say you did?* rather than *You did what?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual way to ask someone to repeat something, whether it's because you didn't understand or couldn't hear, does not depend on what they said. A very common way of doing it, though it is considered rude by many, is simply to say "**What?**"

If you don't want to risk being thought rude, a very polite way of doing it is to say "I'm sorry, **could you repeat that**, please?"

There's a lot in between. "**Pardon?**", "**I beg your pardon?**", "**Beg pardon?**", "**Excuse me?**", "**Sorry?**", and plenty more. Preferences will depend on dialect.

If you were to simply ask "**you did what?**" when someone has told you what they did, it would usually be said in certain tones, and **expresses incredulity** at what they told you, rather than just asking them to say it again because you didn't catch it. It might mean you literally have **trouble believing it**, or that you believe it but you are **angry about it**.

Comment: (I forgot to accept some of the answers for my questions. I apologize.)

Answer (score -1):

'Hai fatto cosa'

If the intent is to have them say it again, or you didn't understand or hear what they said, etc.

Could say:

- "What?"
- "What did you do?" or "What'd you do?"
- "What'd you say?"
- "Say that again?"
- "Pardon?"
- "You did what? .. sorry I didn't hear/understand/etc"